# How To Navigate Between Pages with PageView and NavigationBar Together- Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation, flutter-pageview

I want to navigate different pages with pageview and navigationbar together. These pages will have different Scaffolds because some pages include appbar some don't. I see different examples but all of them use the same scaffold but different body widgets. How can I do that?

I am thinking of using PageView as a parent widget and all of the other pages will be in the list. Also, I will add these pages parameter for the navigation bar index. So when I go to another page by swiping, a new page will come and at this new page, because of the index that I am getting as a parameter, navigationbar item will be seen as selected. Is it a viable solution? I don't want to cripple my app performance

Answer (score 0):

If I got your problem right, You Could use the main screen to have another screen under as using the bottom navigation to the main screen and give the other screens to the bottom navigation and make the main Scaffold to take the screens by making the screen you want to use in the body of the main Scaffold and change its index with the bottom navigation and the page view and then you can have a scaffold for each page like the example below:

```
PageView(
  physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
  controller: _pageViewController,
  children: cubit.screens,
  onPageChanged: (index) {
    cubit.changeIndex(index);
  },
),
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
  currentIndex: cubit.currentIndex,
  onTap: (index) {
    if (index == 2) {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => NewPostScreen(),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      _pageViewController.animateToPage(
        index,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
        curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn
      );
      cubit.changeIndex(index);
    }
  },
  items: const[
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(Iconsax.home_11),
      label: 'News Feed',
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(Iconsax.notification5),
      label:  'Notifications',
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(Iconsax.add),
      label: 'New Post',
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(Iconsax.people5),
      label:  'Users',
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(Iconsax.profile_2user5),
      label: 'Profile',
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: Yeah I can add screens to main Scaffold's body as widgets but some pages don't have Appbar.

Answer (score 0):

my solution is adding `setstate indexNumber` into each of the button that is not includes in the appbar, for example if i have 3 items menu in the appbar, then it containt indexNumber = 0, 1, 2. the other button outside of appbar, you can add like indexNumber = 3, 4 and so on as you need.